# Tools for collaborative development

Tags: android, collaboration

I have developed apps on my own, but now I'm working with a mate.

What is the best way for multiple people to work on the same project and submit the changes?

Is this possible without a 3rd party server? Are their plugins for Eclipse that can solve this problem?

Comment: http://subclipse.tigris.org/

Comment: github or bitbucket. Why do you afraid of servers?

Comment: If you dont want to remain dumb, use servers, or use memory sticks instead. You can label the folder with the date and who modified you will have a history.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plenty of tools that will let you accomplish this.

Version control software such as subversion, mercurial, and Git will all accomplish this task. Git is currently the most popular of the three.

Depending in if you care about keeping to code private, the simplest path forward would be to create a repository on GitHub (private repo's cost money) or  BitBucket (allows private repos for free accounts).

If you don't want to involve a 3rd party then you'll need to setup a repository on a computer that both you and your collaborator can access.

Comment: just took a look at BitBucket. As far as I understood nobody except the owner team can view code in a private repo?

Comment: Many people can all be members of a private repo

Answer (score 0):

### 3rd Party approach

*BitBucket* is an online hosting site for Git and Mercurial which also offers a hosted wiki, issue tracker and source code. But you asked for an approach without a 3rd party (which I find perfectly reasonable) so here are some pointers

### Doing it on your own

- *For Version Control:* Git. "Bare Repositories" allow you to share code w/o a Server as simple as by a shared network directory.
  *But:* Git is quite complex. You might want VisualSVN which is an easy GUI-driven Subversion-Server capable of running on one of your PCs.
- *For Issue Tracking:* JIRA offers a 10$ edition bundled with other useful tools like Bamboo.
- *A Wiki for Documentation:* Many options here.
- *Turnkey Redmine* is a virtual appliance (downloadable image of a virtual machine). Just download and run i.e. inside VirtualBox and you quickly get a *Version control, issue tracker, Wiki and other services* in short time.